# jQuery .load to load SOME of the contents of a div from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'd like to create a module that, based on user interaction, will show products from product category using the `jquery.load` method.

I can make the target div load the entire contents of the product list from the product page, but is there a way to limit the number of child elements of the remote (so to speak) div to, say, 8?

Put simply:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".cat1").click(function() {
alert('click');
jQuery(".loadhere").load("cat1.php #product_list", function() { alert('loaded') }
);
})
});
</script>
```

I would like this to just load the first 8 div's found within #product_list — is this possible?

Comment: It seems to me that you would have to handle that in the callback function. Check the request / response cycle in Firebug and you'll see that the whole page is actually returned and that load handles getting the #product_list in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your code to use `ajax` and then handling the response yourself in the callback.  Something like this:

```
$(data).find("#product_list .product").slice(0,9).appendTo(".loadhere");
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, real ajax is a bit scary to me, but ill give it a go.  im still surprised there is no jquery way to do it.  i supose i could wrap the first 8 records in a separate div on the target page.